# impdp does not accept two tables in an INCLUDE Command

Tags: oracle

When restoring a table from an oracle 11g backup, including more than 2 entries in the INCLUDE command returns syntax error.

The command that works is:

```
impdp SVC_DEMO/********* SCHEMAS=test REMAP_SCHEMA=test:SVC_DEMO REMAP_TABLESPACE=DATA:SYSTEM DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=devv2db_05102016.dmp TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=replace INCLUDE = TABLE:"IN('TBLPARTNER')" LOGFILE=impschema1.log 
Starting "SVC_DEMO"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_02":  SVC_DEMO/********      
SCHEMAS=test REMAP_SCHEMA=test:SVC_DEMO 
REMAP_TABLESPACE=DATA:SYSTEM DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=devv2db_05102016.dmp 
LOGFILE=impschema1.log 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "SVC_DEMO"."TBLPARTNER"                   21.46 KB       7 rows
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Job "SVC_DEMO"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_02" successfully completed at 15:01:38
```

But, when I add a second table in the include command:

```
impdp SVC_DEMO/********* SCHEMAS=test REMAP_SCHEMA=test:SVC_DEMO REMAP_TABLESPACE=DATA:SYSTEM DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=devv2db_05102016.dmp TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=replace INCLUDE = TABLE:"IN('TBLPARTNER', 'TBLACCOUNT')" LOGFILE=impschema1.log
```

I get the following message:

```
impdp SVC_DEMO/****** SCHEMAS=test REMAP_SCHEMA=test:SVC_DEMO
REMAP_TABLESPACE=DATA:SYSTEM DIRECTORY=dmpdir
DUMPFILE=devv2db_05102016.dmp TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=replace INCLUDE =
TABLE:"IN('TBLPARTNER', 'TBLACCOUNT')" LOGFILE=impschema1.log 

LRM-00116: syntax error at ')' following 'TBLACCOUNT'
```

I have looked for bugs in impdp but can't find one.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 1. - format your code (edit, select code, CTRL-K, adjust indentations); 2. Is this MySQL, SQL Server, or Oracle? (while you are editing your post, scroll down to the bottom, click the small x on tags that don't apply to you.) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running this on command line, depending on your OS, special characters may need to be escaped. (It's also easier to use a parameter file where you wont need to escape the characters)

```
include=TABLE:\"IN \(\'TABLE1\', \'TABLE2\'\)\"
```

Using a parameter file you just place one option per line and reference it with

```
impdp PARFILE=name.txt
```

Comment: Initially, I followed your first recommendation, and it did not work. Then, I followed your second recommendation, use a parametric file and this does work. Maybe, there is a bug in the command line version of impdp. Thanks and I will use only parametric files.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Could be that you only have to escape quotation marks  (\") or only escape Apostrophe ( \' ) using the command line.